# Dropbox oauth2.0: Cross origin issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, cross-domain, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to authorize my app using the dropbox oauth 2.0 but getting Cross origin issue. I made a GET request to https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize
with **response_type**: 'code' and **client_id** but keep getting the cross origin issue.

When using this "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorizeclient_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code" directly in the browser, I am redirected to the dropbox authorization page as expected.

Am I missing anything in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [/authorize page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize) (https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize...) is only a web page that users should be interacting with in their browser. It isn't an API endpoint so you shouldn't be attempting to call it programmatically.

If you're implementing the OAuth 2 app authorization flow, this blog post may be useful:

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/07/using-oauth-2-0-with-the-core-api/